# Make header only partially fixed when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I didn't really know how to express what I want in the title. I want my header to be a big image and below that a standard header. When you scroll down, I want the image to disappear to the top until the standard header is at the top, I then want the standard header to be fixed when scrolling down.

```
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|              IMAGE              |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
|              HEADER             |
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|                                 |
|               PAGE              |
|                                 |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

So far I have the Header and a side navigation bar working. I don't even know how to approach the image part of the header, though. What I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/kenogo99/q1Lo9qy1/

I'd probably have to create an extra div for the image but I don't know how to make the header first scroll up and then stay there.

Comment: Basically, something like this? http://www.haaretz.com/

Comment: Here's a great demo on how to do it. You will need to use some JS. https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn

Comment: This site is using that: http://www.fbl.co.nz/ it is using the sticky nav plugin: http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky

Comment: @IsabelInc Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. How do I use the JavaScript code, though? I just copied the code that was written in your link into an html file and into a css file, then I took the javascript and put it into the head of my html using <script>. I guess that was wrong, because everything works except the navigation actually sticking.

Comment: Could you update your fiddle with the new code?

Comment: @IsabelInc If I literally copy the code into a fiddle, this is what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/kenogo99/q1Lo9qy1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to include JQuery in your fiddle.

You can add it by clicking on the gear icon in the fiddle JavaScript panel and then adding JQuery in frameworks.

You can reference JQuery in your code by using the $ or JQuery variable. Since JQuery is missing, it says $ is not defined in the console.

You should always use the web inspector and check out the console for errors. Usually missing dependencies throw a `'ReferenceError: *Something* is not defined'` like in the screenshot below.

[image: Console]
Hope this helps.

Cheers and happy coding!